# Printf with predefined macro concatenate with strings has format specifier in C

Tags: c, macros

I'm programming in Windows and MSVC. There are two ways to write a DEBUG_PRINT statement as I know of:

```
printf(__FUNCTION__": Error code: %x\n", ErrorCode); 
printf("%s: Error code: %x\n", __FUNCTION__, ErrorCode);
```

Is it okay to concatenate predefined macro with strings like this? I don't know if predefined macro like `__FUNCTION__` or `__LINE__`  is a legit string literal. And intuitively, seems like a dangerous way to treat strings like this in C.

And what's the difference between these two? As I used /FAcs compiler option to output the code snippet to assembly, I really can't see much of a difference.

Comment: How have you defined `FUNCTION` and `LINE`? None of them are predefined macros. If you mean `__FUNCTION__` then it's not a macro, but more like a local variable - that means it doesn't work with string concatenation.

Comment: Unless you want to use compiler extensions (`__FUNCTION__` is not a [standard predefined macro](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/preprocessor/replace#Predefined_macros)) and backwards compatibility, then you should use the C99 symbol [`__func__`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/function_definition#func) which is a special *variable* containing the current function name. Since it's a variable you need to use the second variant.

Comment: But the statement could be compiled and looks like it runs normally. Just a gut feeling that this isn't right, but I can't find anywhere to prove it.

Comment: Also, if you read e.g. [the GCC manual for "Function Names as Strings"](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html) you will first see that it's part of the chapter on [extensions to the C language](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html#C-Extensions), then also see "`__FUNCTION__` is another name for `__func__`, provided for backward compatibility with old versions of GCC." So in later versions of GCC it's not a preprocessor macro anymore, but an alias of the `__func__` *variable*, and you can't use string literal concatenation with it. So migrate away from it.

Comment: The first method can takes up more space.  The second can fold the repetitive `"%s: Error code: %x\n"` into one instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The former will concatenate the function name in `__FUNCTION__` with the format string at compile-time. The second will format it into the output at runtime.

This assumes it's a pre-defined macro (it's not standard). MSVC has `__FUNCTION__` as a proper string literal, GCC does not.

`__LINE__` is supported by GCC, and expands to a decimal integer, i.e. not a string.

For performance reasons, I would suggest always using the first way when possible, i.e. when the two strings are compile-time constant. There will be a price to pay, as usual: the string pool will be larger, since each use of the macro creates a unique format string. For desktop-class systems, this is probably neglible.

Comment: In GCC `__FUNCTION__` is a define for `__func__` which by the C standard is defined to not be a string literal and can't be concatenated this way.

Comment: Thanks, I think I just overreacted. Seems like the first way is okay.

Answer (score 2):

First of all `__FUNCTION__` is not in the C standard, you should probably use `__func__` instead (except that microsoft has decided to skip support for that in their C compiler).

Second `__FUNCTION__`/`__func__` "macro" is not really a macro (or at least not normally - microsoft's compiler seem to behave differently), it behaves more like a local variable and therefore it isn't a candidate for the string concatenation. You should use string formatting instead (since that will ensure that your code will become more portable).

The `__LINE__` macro (is a macro), but it doesn't work well with string concatenation directly since it doesn't expand to a string - it expands to a number (which by the way can be useful in other cases). However you can use the preprocessor to stringify it (the `XSTR` macro will first expand it's argument and then stringify the result while `STR` will not expand the it's argument before stringifying it):

```
#define STR(x) # x
#define XSTR(x) STR(x)

printf("I'm on line #" XSTR(__LINE__));
```

The `__FILE__` macro (which is also a macro) does expand to a string literal which plays well together with string concatenation directly.

The reason you don't see any difference is that the compiler knows what `printf` does and can use that for optimization. It would figure out that it doesn't need to rely on `printf` code to expand the `%s` at runtime since it can do it at compile time.

Comment: Thanks! Learn a lot from you.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that in the 1st case the string literal gets concatenated with the format string during the compiler translation phases, while in the second case, it gets read in during run-time. So the first method is much faster.

If you know that the macro is a pre-defined string literal, I don't see anything wrong with the code.

That being said, I have no idea what `__FUNCTION__` is. There is a standard C macro `__func__` but it is not a string literal and should be treated like a const char array.

`__LINE__` is a standard C macro that gives the source file line as an integer.

Comment: In fact I don't, MSDN described them as predefined macro, just have to buy it.

Comment: @Gilvin You can easily test it by printing the `sizeof` the macro. If it is a string literal it will have a variable size, otherwise if it is a pointer, it will be 4 or 8 bytes etc. With standard C compilers you could also use `_Generic` to know the type at compile-time, but VS is not a standard compiler.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answering. Looks like the first way is a legit literal string concatenate, it just does it in build-time, and it's faster, just space consuming.

I think I'll stick in the first way. Thanks again.